# Selenium C# expression in Visual Studio using contains in a PageSource does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following Selenium command in Visual Studio 2012:

```
if (wd.PageSource.Contains("TestUser99"))
```

When I run the test it shows this statement fails. When I debug this I can see the string in the page source! Am I using `.Contains()` incorrectly?

I have attempted to use HTML Tag name, CSS selector and ID; all of these fail. I am not sure if maybe the user text exists in the header if so would this change page source?

Comment: You need to post more of your code.  Are you using the `driver` to find the element?

Comment: This an horrific way to search for something in a web page. It's a sin.

Comment: Arran I agree but all of the other attempts have failed so I am trying this as a last resort and dont understand why it does not work when I can see it in the Page Source.

Comment: Well I'd backtrack a few steps. This text must exist in some **element** somewhere in your HTML page. So let's start there. Selenium has these methods for a reason, it's so that you don't go blindly searching the entire source of the page for this. So please post the HTML that surrounds that text and what types of locators you've used, and what errors you get. This method here, is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: if (wd.FindElement(By.TagName("html")).Text.Contains("TestUser99"))

Comment: if (wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[id^='idhere'] span.TestUser99")).Text) and if (wd.FindElement(By.Id("idhere")).GetAttribute("value") != "TestUser99")

Comment: You can edit your question and add information.  In this case, it would be very helpful to have a link to the page, or failing that, the HTML of the element you're trying to query.

Comment: Real HTML, real code, real ID's, real locators.

Answer (score -2):

I think your problem is syntax:

```
if (wd.PageSource.Contains("TestUser99"))
```

Is not the normal form.

Try:

```
driver.getPageSource().contains("sometext");
```

Comment: He's using c#, what you posted is Java syntax.  His syntax is correct for c#.

Comment: I use wd instead of driver. When I attempt to use driver I get this name does not exist in this context.